# Function definitions not being applied when using replacements or lists with fractional steps

Tags: function-construction, replacement, list-manipulation, downvalues

I am attempting to use `Table` to evaluate a function at specific values.  The function is first defined.

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x/y];
```

The known definitions are applied

```
f[x_, 0] = 1;

?f
Global`f
f[x_,0]=1

f[x_,y_]=ArcTan[x/y]
```

And the function is tested

```
f[x, 0]

1
```

Using replacement

```
f[x, y] /. y -> 0

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Indeterminate
```

Using lists

```
Table[f[x, y], {y, -1, 1, 0.5}]

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

{-ArcTan[1. x], -ArcTan[2. x], Indeterminate, ArcTan[2. x], 
 ArcTan[1. x]}
```

Interestingly enough, this seems to only fail when the list steps are fractional

```
Table[f[x, y], {y, -1, 1, 1}]

{-ArcTan[x], 1, ArcTan[x]}
```

Why is the known value of the function not being used to provide a solution is these specific instances?

Note that whether the definition is delayed or not does not have an effect on this behavior.

Comment: try `Hold[f[x, y]] /. y -> 0 // ReleaseHold` or `Unevaluated[f[x, y]] /. y -> 0 // Evaluate`?

Comment: and try `Trace[f[x, y] /. y -> 0] // Column` to see what is happening.

Comment: In your first `Table` example, it fails because it's using machine precision numbers due to the 0.5. Either change it to `{y, -1, 1, 1/2}` to make them exact numbers, or add `f[x_, 0.] = 1` somewhere to tell it that it should treat a machine precision zero in the same way as exact zero.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you both.  I'll do some reading on Mathematica's handling of numerical precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f[x,y]` is evaluated to `ArcTan[x/y]` before `ReplaceAll` gets to work. This is because `ReplaceAll` has a low precedence:

```
Precedence /@ {f[x, y], ReplaceAll}
```

> ```
> {1000., 110.}
> ```

You can prevent evaluation of `f[x,y]` before replacement of `y` with `0` using any of the following

```
Unevaluated[f[x, y]] /. y -> 0 // Evaluate
Hold[f[x, y]] /. y -> 0 // ReleaseHold
Inactive[f][x, y] /. y -> 0 // Activate
Inactivate[f[x, y], f] /. y -> 0 // Activate
```

all give `1`.

Use [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) to see the source of error:

```
Trace[f[x, y] /. y -> 0] // Column
```

[image]

Pre-mature evaluation does not happen in `Table` example (because `Table` has attribute `HoldAll`). As noted by MassDefect in comments, you need to modify the definition of `f` to specify  both `f[x_,0]` and `f[x_,0.]` are  `1` to avoid the error message:

```
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x/y];
f[x_, 0 | 0.] = 1;
Table[f[x, y], {y, -1, 1, .5}]
```

> ```
>   {-ArcTan[1. x], -ArcTan[2. x], 1, ArcTan[2. x], ArcTan[1. x]}
> ```